# Login with Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

My security.yml

```yaml
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
providers:
    my_entity_provider:
                entity:
                    class:              AppBundle:User
                    property:           email

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        provider: my_entity_provider
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
          username_parameter: _email
          login_path: login
          check_path: login
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
        #http_basic: ~

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
        #form_login: ~
```

My controller:

```
class SecurityController extends Controller{
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authUtils)
{
    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authUtils->getLastUsername();

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error,
    ));
}
```

My twig:

```
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}
<form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
    <button type="submit">login</button>
</form>
```

So i try to login with email and password but i always get bad credentils.
Can some one tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: show the query you are using in the user loader

Comment: Paste into the stack overflow search bar: symfony bad credentials and read through the many possible causes

Answer (score 0):

your username_parameter doesnt correspond with your input field of your twig.

check also https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#username-parameter

Answer (score -1):

If you have follow this [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html#using-a-custom-query-to-load-the-user) check you are using the email in your query as well.

Comment: Just for info, the security.yml file tells you that the OP is using the Symfony user provider and the email property.

Comment: Please add all information to the answer itself instead of linking to external sites